# CentOS 7, Win 10 - Having boot option on startup

Tags: centos

A while ago I installed Ubuntu on an old computer and I had the option to choose on startup whether I wanted to boot into Ubuntu or Windows (was probably Vista at the time). Now on my newer computer (running windows 10) I have installed CentOS 7 on a separate HDD. Is there a way to get the option of OS on startup like I had before? I'm currently having to change boot priorities in BIOS which is not ideal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to modify bootloader of CentOS (GRUB in most case) and add an entry to load Windows.

The entry is as follow:

```
menuentry "Windows" {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ntfs
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  chainloader +1
}
```

Let's say your Windows is on the first HDD (hd0) and CentOS is on second HDD (hd1). Assuming that Windows is install on first partition, therefore it is 'msdos1' .

Comment: I added this to 40_custom but the option still does not appear in the grub bootloader